# MySQL - MIN and MAX value with empty fields

Tags: mysql, max, min

I'm trying to write an SQL that will allow me to return the minimum value for a start time and a maximum time for an end time. My problem is that in the table I can have empty rows and when I do a MIN on an empty field it returns me an empty value. I can't do `begin_service! = ''` because I may not have values, in this case I must have an empty result. This is my table :

| app_id | function_id | begin_service | end_service |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| B125 | 12 |  |  |
| B125 | 13 |  |  |
| B125 | 54 |  |  |
| C789 | 98 |  |  |
| C789 | 12 | 06:00 | 18:00 |
| C789 | 15 | 08:00 | 20:00 |
| C789 | 78 |  |  |

My SQL :

```
SELECT app_id, MIN(begin_service), MAX(end_service)
FROM applications
GROUP BY app_id;
```

Result :

| app_id | begin_service | begin_service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B125 |  |  |
| C789 |  | 20:00 |

Desired result :

| app_id | begin_service | begin_service |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B125 |  |  |
| C789 | 06:00 | 20:00 |

Can you help me ?

Comment: how c789 has min time 06:00 ? 06:00 belongs to C783.

Comment: sorry,it was a typo

Comment: what is the datatype you have for begin_service and end_service

Comment: It's a string @AmitVerma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two subqueries to get the empty and non-empty minimum values for each `app_id`. Combine them with `UNION` and then take the max of that to prefer the non-empty value.

```
SELECT app_id, MAX(begin_service) AS begin_service, MAX(end_service) AS end_service
FROM (
    SELECT app_id, MIN(begin_service) AS begin_service, MAX(end_service) AS end_service
    FROM applications
    WHERE begin_service != ''
    GROUP BY app_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT app_id, '', MAX(end_service)
    FROM applications
    WHERE begin_service = ''
    GROUP BY app_id
) AS x
GROUP BY app_id
```